# I am trying to send a range in google sheets as a pdf in an email. My script is getting stuck on getid()

Tags: javascript, arrays, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a macro in Google scripts that sends me an email of a worksheet I created. When I try to run this, the script gets stuck at the function GetSheetID(). (4th line of 2nd function)

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetId' of undefined (line 51, file "macros")"

I am open to other email techniques as well. My main goal is to take a range and send as a picture or PDF in an email.

```
function sendSheetToPdfwithA1MailAdress(){ // this is the function to call
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[4]; // it will send sheet 0 which is the first sheet in the spreadsheet.
  // if you change the number, change it also in the parameters below
  var shName = 4 //sh.getName()
  
  var shNum = 4
  var shRng = 'A1:R35'
  var pdfName = 'Automated Snapshot'
  var email = 'email@gmail.com'
  var subject = 'Daily Snapshot'
  var htmlbody = ''
  mailPdf(shNum,shRng,pdfName,email,subject,htmlbody);
}

function mailPdf(shNum,shRng,pdfName,email,subject,htmlbody) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var shId = shNum ? ss.getSheets()[shNum].getSheetId() : null;  
  var url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
      + (shId ? ('&gid=' + shId) : ('&id=' + ssId))
      + (shRng ? ('&range=E1:L25') : null)
      + '&format=pdf'                   //export format
      + '&size=letter'                      //A3/A4/A5/B4/B5/letter/tabloid/legal/statement/executive/folio
      //+ '&portrait=false'               //true= Portrait / false= Landscape
      //+ '&scale=1'                      //1= Normal 100% / 2= Fit to width / 3= Fit to height / 4= Fit to Page
      //+ '&top_margin=0.00'              //All four margins must be set!
      //+ '&bottom_margin=0.00'           //All four margins must be set!
      //+ '&left_margin=0.00'             //All four margins must be set!
      //+ '&right_margin=0.00'            //All four margins must be set!
      + '&gridlines=false'              //true/false
      //+ '&printnotes=false'             //true/false
      //+ '&pageorder=2'                  //1= Down, then over / 2= Over, then down
      //+ '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER'  //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
      + '&vertical_alignment=TOP'       //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
      //+ '&printtitle=false'             //true/false
      //+ '&sheetnames=false'             //true/false
      //+ '&fzr=false'                    //true/false frozen rows
      //+ '&fzc=false'                    //true/false frozen cols
      //+ '&attachment=false'             //true/false

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      'muteHttpExceptions': true
    }
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  if (email) {
    var mailOptions = {
      attachments:blob, htmlBody:htmlbody
    }


MailApp.sendEmail(
      // email + "," + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() // use this to email self and others
      email,                                              // use this to only email users requested
      subject+' (' + pdfName +')', 
      'html content only', 
      mailOptions);

  }
}
```

Comment: What to you mean by "the script gets stuck at the function GetSheetID(). (4th line of 2nd function)"? If you got an error add the textual error to the question. Also add a brief description of your spreadsheet, specially about its attributes that are related to the script like the number of sheets.

Comment: The error i get reads: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetId' of undefined (line 51, file "macros")"

Comment: I'd guess that your active spreadsheet does not have five sheets.

Comment: I added another sheet and ran the script. Now i am getting a different error that reads:      "Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: <HTML> <HEAD> <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"> <H1>Unauthorized</H1> <H2>Error 401</H2> </BODY> </HTML> (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 82, file "macros")"

Comment: line 82 reads: var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetId' of undefined (line 51, file "macros")"

It's very likely that you are using base one index instead of a zero based index and that your spreadsheet has less than 5 sheets.

The fix depends on which sheet id do you want to assign to `shId` of the following code line:

```
var shId = shNum ? ss.getSheets()[shNum].getSheetId() : null;
```

Reference

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array